# How to add phone number to my list of properties?

Tags: powershell

I have created a function that will generate a list of users & their properties from AD, organize them into teams, and export them to an excel sheet. How do I add phone numbers to the list of properties? I have tried to use Get-ADUser, but I can't seem to figure out how to select the users name's from the list and import it into Get-ADUser.

Here is my code:

```
FUNCTION Get-FieldOpsTeamMemberList{
<#
    .SYNOPSIS
    Generates list of technicians and their properties for each Field Service Team.

    .Description
    Generates list of technicians and their properties for each Field Service Team.
    It is able to generate a list of technicians for one team name, multiple team names, or all team names.

    .Parameter Team
    Team has to be a string variable or list of string variables. 

    If value passed to team doesn't match a Field Service Team then it will error out.

    .Example
    Get-FieldOpsTeamMemberList -Team CapF

    .Example
    Get-FieldOpsTeamMemberList CapF

    .NOTES

    Created on: 12/22/2021
    Created by: BlahBlah
    FileName:FieldOps.ps1
#>

[CmdletBinding()]
param
(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
    [ValidateSet("CapA","CapB","CapC","CapD","CapE","CapF","Delivery","Network","NorthA","NorthB","NorthC","Projects","SouthA","SouthB","SouthC","SouthD","All")]
    [String[]]$Team,
    [ValidateSet("Console","Console-Formatted","CSV","Gridview")]
    [String]$OutputFormat = 'Gridview',
    [String]$OutputPath
)
TRY{
    #region Validation
        IF($OutputFormat -eq "CSV" -and $OutputPath -like $null){
            Write-Output "Get-FieldOpsMemberList -Team CapD -OutputFormat CSV -OutputPath [Path] is required if intending to export to CSV."
            RETURN
        }
    #endregion
    #region Define Mapping
        $FieldTeamGroupMapping = @{
            'CapA' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2A'
            'CapB' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2B'
            'CapC' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2C'
            'CapD' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2D'
            'CapE' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2E'
            'CapF' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-2F'
            'Delivery' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-Delivery'
            'Network' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-Network'
            'NorthA' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-North-A'
            'NorthB' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-North-B'
            'NorthC' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-North-C'
            'Projects' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-Projects-1361711097'
            'SouthA' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-A'
            'SouthB' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-B'
            'SouthC' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-C'
            'SouthD' = '_DOA-OTS-Ivanti-Team-OTS-EUC-Field-South-D'
        }
    #endregion
    #region All
        if($Team -contains 'ALL')
        {
            # If the user specified `ALL`, resolve all team names
            $Team = $FieldTeamGroupMapping.Keys | Sort-Object

        }
    #endregion
    #region Loop over list of team names and pull membership
        $matchedData = @()
        ForEach($teamName in $Team)
        {
            # If the user input does not contain a team name, display team name isn't recognized
            IF(-not $FieldTeamGroupMapping.ContainsKey($teamName))
            {
                Write-Error "Team name '$teamName' is not recognized"
            }
            ELSE
            {
                $matchedData += TRY{Get-ADGroupMember $FieldTeamGroupMapping[$teamName] -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object @{Label="Team";Expression={$teamName}},Name,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName}CATCH{Write-Host -fo Red ($_.Exception.Message | Out-String)}
            }
        }
        $matchedData = $matchedData | Where-Object {$_.Team -like "*[A-Za-z0-9]*"}
    #endregion
    #region Output
        SWITCH($OutputFormat){
            "Console" {
                Write-Output ($matchedData | Select-Object Team,Name,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName)
                break
            }
            "Console-Formatted" {
                $matchedData | Group-Object Team | ForEach-Object {
                    Write-Host "************************************************"
                    $_.Group | Select-Object Name,SamAccountName,DistinguishedName | Format-Table -AutoSize
                }
                break
            }
            "CSV" {
                TRY{
                    $matchedData | Export-CSV -Path $OutputPath -Force -NoTypeInformation -Confirm:$false
                    . $OutputPath
                }
                CATCH{
                    Write-Output "Export failed for the following reason:"
                    $_.Exception.Message
                    break
                }
            }
            "Gridview" {
                $matchedData | Out-GridView
                break
            }
        }
    #endregion
    #region Cleanup
        Remove-Variable Team,OutputFormat,OutputPath -Force -WarningAction SilentlyContinue -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
        [System.GC]::Collect()
        RETURN
    #endregion
}
CATCH{
    Write-Host -fo Yellow ($_.Exception.Message | Out-String)
}}
```

Comment: You need to narrow down the part of your function you need help with there is no need to paste the entire function. Out of all statements, which one is the one you need to update?

Comment: And.. which telephone number would you want in there. Take your pick, there's `homePhone`, `telephoneNumber`, `mobile`, `ipPhone`, `facsimileTelephoneNumber`, `otherHomePhone`, `otherTelephone`, `otherIpPhone`, `otherMobile`, `otherFacsimileTelephoneNumber` etcetera..

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
$a = Get-ADUser -Identity Put_here_your_SamAccountName -Properties telephoneNumber
$a.telephoneNumber
```

use :

```
Get-ADUser -Identity Put_here_your_SamAccountName -Properties *
```

to see all the properties